# Cannot ping containers in the same pod in Kubernetes(minikube)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

On my local I run a `mysql` container and then ping it from another container on the same network:

```
$ docker run -d tutum/mysql
$ docker run -it plumsempy/plum bash
    # ping MYSQL_CONTAINER_ID

      PING 67e35427d638 (198.105.244.24): 56 data bytes
      64 bytes from 198.105.244.24: icmp_seq=0 ttl=37 time=0.243 ms 
      ...
```

That is good. Then, using Kubernetes(minikube) locally, I deploy tutum/mysql using the following `YAML`:

```
...
- name: mysql
  image: tutum/mysql
...
```

There is nothing else for the `mysql` container. Then I deploy it, ssh into the minikube pod, spin up a random container and try pinging the mysql container inside the pod this time:

```
$ kubectl create -f k8s-deployment.yml
$ minikube ssh
    $ docker ps
    $ docker run -it plumsempy/plum bash
        # ping MYSQL_CONTAINER_ID_INSIDE_MINIKUBE

          PING mysql (198.105.244.24): 56 data bytes
          ^C--- mysql ping statistics ---
          10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

        # traceroute MYSQL_CONTAINER_ID_INSIDE_MINIKUBE

          traceroute to aa7f7ed7af01 (198.105.244.24), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
           1  172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1)  0.031 ms  0.009 ms  0.007 ms
           2  10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2)  0.156 ms  0.086 ms  0.050 ms
           3  * * *
           4  * * *
           5  dtr02gldlca-tge-0-2-0-1.gldl.ca.charter.com (96.34.102.201)  16.153 ms  16.107 ms  16.077 ms
           6  crr01lnbhca-bue-200.lnbh.ca.charter.com (96.34.98.188)  18.753 ms  18.011 ms  30.642 ms
           7  crr01mtpkca-bue-201.mtpk.ca.charter.com (96.34.96.63)  30.779 ms  30.523 ms  30.428 ms
           8  bbr01mtpkca-bue-2.mtpk.ca.charter.com (96.34.2.24)  24.089 ms  23.900 ms  23.814 ms
           9  bbr01ashbva-tge-0-1-0-1.ashb.va.charter.com (96.34.3.139)  26.061 ms  25.949 ms  36.002 ms
           10  10ge9-10.core1.lax1.he.net (65.19.189.177)  34.027 ms  34.436 ms  33.857 ms
           11  100ge12-1.core1.ash1.he.net (184.105.80.201)  107.873 ms  107.750 ms  104.078 ms
           12  100ge3-1.core1.nyc4.he.net (184.105.223.166)  100.554 ms  100.478 ms  100.393 ms
           13  xerocole-inc.10gigabitethernet12-4.core1.nyc4.he.net (216.66.41.242)  109.184 ms  111.122 ms  111.018 ms
           14  * * *
           15  * * * 
           ...(til it ends)
```

the `plumsempy/plum` can be any container since they are both on the same network and same pod, the pinging should go through. The question is **Why can I not reach `mysql` on minikube and how could I fix that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [k8s multi-container pod docs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/multi-container/):

> Pods share fate, and share some resources, such as storage volumes and IP addresses.

Hence the `mysql` container is reachable from the `plum` container at the IP address `127.0.0.1`.

Also, since `mysql` runs on port 3306 by default, you probably want `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306` to check if it's reachable (`ping` uses ICMP which doesn't have the concept of ports).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the container ID just don't work with Kubernetes. You can also see, that the container ID resolved to the public IP `198.105.244.24`, which looks wrong.

You have multiple ways to contact this pod:

- get the pod IP via `kubectl describe -f k8s-deployment.yml`
- create a [service](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/) for that pod and do one of these (assuming the service name is `mysql`):

  - use [environment variables](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#environment-variables) like `ping ${MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST}`
  - use [DNS](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#dns) like `ping mysql.default.svc.cluster.local`